# Any infinite subset of totally bounded metric space contains infinite subsets of arbitrarily small diameter.

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-writing, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

This is a problem from my metric space book,I want to know if my proof is correct and whether the proof can be simplified:

**Statement:** Suppose $X$ is a totally bounded and $A\subset X$ is infinite,then for each $\epsilon>0$,$A$ has an infinite subset $B$ such that $diam(B)\leq \epsilon$.

Proof: Since $A$ is infinite,we can take a sequence of distinct terms from $A$,Now this sequence $(x_n)$ must have a Cauchy subsequence by the total boundedness of $X$(sequential criterion).Suppose the subsequence is $(x_{r_n})$.Then given $\epsilon>0$,we can find $n_\epsilon\in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall m,n\geq n_\epsilon$,$d(x_{r_n},x_{r_m})<\epsilon/2$.So after a given stage $n_\epsilon$,all the terms fit in a ball of radius $\epsilon/2$ centred at $x_{r_{n_\epsilon}}$.So if we take $B=\{x_{r_n}:n\geq n_{\epsilon}\}$,which is infinite as terms are distinct ,then $diam(B)\leq \epsilon$.

Is the above proof alright?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @NateEldredge I have to make an edit.

Comment: One small error. You can only say $diam(B) \leq \epsilon$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy replace $\epsilon$ by $\epsilon/2$ then.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy No,it will be strictly $<$ because $B=B(x,r_{x_{n_{\epsilon}}} )\cap B$ and we can show that diameter of the open ball is strictly $<\epsilon$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy By use of $\triangle$ inequality.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar If each element of  a set is less than $\epsilon$ it does not follow that the supremum of the set is also less than $\epsilon$.  You can only say that the supremum is **less than or equal to** $\epsilon$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy replace ϵ by ϵ/2 then.